# how to change the string display

Tags: android, string

how can i change string 980302 to string 98/03/02 in android studio

I have a variable of type string, for example 980302 I want to represent this way 98/03/02 in edittext Is
 there a way?
Thanks for helping

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do that. Seeing the format I think you are using date so I would recommend you to use calendar object to store date

Comment: add some code and explain why do you need to do that

Comment: getting the result for your requirement is not that difficult, but do provide a proper explanation for your question. what is the input for this work and what exactly you need, as generic as possible. also try to do a few tricks by your own first and provide them here so that anyone can get clear idea to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the most trivial way of doing this...

```
String a = "980302";
String b = "" + a.charAt(0) + a.charAt(1) + "/" + a.charAt(2) + a.charAt(3) + "/" + a.charAt(4) + a.charAt(5);
YOUR_EDIT_TEXT.setText(b);
```

Or with a loop:

```
String a = "980302";
String b = "";

int i = 1;
while(i<a.length()){
    if(i == 5){
        b = b + a.charAt(i-1) + a.charAt(i);
    }
    else{
        b = b + a.charAt(i-1) + a.charAt(i) + "/";
    }
    i = i + 2;
}
YOUR_EDIT_TEXT.setText(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking to show 980302 as 98/03/02 while typing, then the answer is using textchange event.

```
mMyEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
    {
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) 
    {

    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
    {
        String str = s.toString();
        if(str.length()==2 || str.length()==5){
           str+= '/';
           //Set str in edittext
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I think he is looking for way(Coding to extract) not textwatcher which will help him to find text.

Comment: I'm not sure if he's asking that simple question

Answer (score 0):

```
a = a.substring(0, 1) + "/" + a.substring(2, 3) + "/" + a.substring(4, 5);
```